# Android Text To Speech TTS not bound to TTS engine after pressing home and back to apps

Tags: java, android, text, text-to-speech

I use TTS with my phone and at the first app launch, tts is working well, but after I press the home button then go back again to my app and try to call event tts, its showing an error like this:

> W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine

I try to use this code

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        refresh();
    }
}
```

It will call the refresh function when TTS error occurs, but it is never called. I think its because of the apps already init for the first launch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to override onResume() method.
Would you concider giving us piece of your code if it doesn't help?